# GFCI Reads Open Hot - Won't reset

Tags: electrical, gfci

I have an outlet in my bathroom that quit working.  Tester reads "open hot".  Outlet is at the end of a run and everything else seems to be working properly.  Tried replacing the GFCI, but still have the same problem.  Any ideas on the likely culprit?

Comment: Does the wire going _to_ the GFCI have voltage on it when the breaker is on?  Even if the GFCI outlet is broken the incoming wire from the breaker box should be hot.  When the GFCI is tripped, the "load" side will have no voltage. Load side will be live when the GFCI is reset.

Comment: What happens if you replace the GFCI with a plain receptacle?  Are you quite sure there is **nothing** attached to the `LOAD` terminals of the GFCI?   And just to be clear, is the problem outlet the GFCI or is it downstream from a GFCI?

Comment: Wire going to the GFCI is hot.  Nothing attached to the load terminals.  Problem is at the outlet (light is red, reset button won't stay in).

Comment: Some of the newer GFCI's need the test button pressed then the reset button pressed before they will activate.

Comment: Yes, what happens when you cycle the test then reset buttons? Also, what make/model is the GFCI in question?

Comment: I pressed the test and reset buttons multiple times and nothing happens.  Reset button won't stay in.  It's a Leviton GFNT1-W.

Comment: @MattWilson -- can you double check to make sure your wires are connected to the GFCI's LINE terminals?

Comment: Yes, they are connected to the line terminals.

Comment: I connected the GFCI in question to another circuit and it worked fine.  Should I just start working my way back on the problem circuit looking for a loose connection or is there a more efficient way to find the problem?

Comment: Is the line to your gfci coming from a light?